# Simple Mobile Tools Keyboard set theme color

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm trying to build the Android project Simple-Keyboard and have the default theme be "Black & White" because the default theme of Dark is too dark for my users.  I tried changing the theme in styles.xml:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.BlackAndWhite" />`

But it still defaults to the dark theme.  I also looked over the code of which most of it resides in the Simple-Commons project and couldn't figure out a code change to make this the default.  I don't want to have to set it manually from the app for every user so that is why I would like to achieve this from either code and/or styles/manifest files.

[Simple-Keyboard](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Keyboard)
[Simple-Commons](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Commons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and the solution is in Simple-Commons repository.  You need to change two values in `commons/src/main/res/values/colors.xml`.  For me I wanted the Black & White theme so I changed:

```
<color name="theme_dark_text_color">@color/md_grey_200</color>
<color name="theme_dark_background_color">@color/md_grey_800</color>
```

to:

```
<color name="theme_dark_text_color">@color/md_grey_black</color>
<color name="theme_dark_background_color">@color/md_grey_white</color>
```

It appears most of the theming when changing it from code is based on color calculations based on the two "default dark theme" values.